# Counting number of lines of code in align* environment

Tags: align, conditionals, counters, setcounter

I am writing an exam paper, and I want to write the solutions immediately after the question. I then want to toggle the solutions on and off, which works via the `\solution` command. When solutions are on, the solution is shown. When solutions are off, I want the `\lines{}` command to print n number of lines, where n is the number of lines in the solution. The command `\lines{3}` would print three lines. In the example below, the solution is 8 lines long, so I want `\value{equation}` to be 8 so that the else case prints 8 lines for this particular question. What should I change to make this work?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle} % change for bigger fonts 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % must include 
\usepackage{exam} % the exam.sty styles 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{xparse} 
\usepackage{lineno} 
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} 

\newif\ifsolutions
\solutionstrue % set to true to show solutions, false to hide solutions

\newcounter{linescount} % Define a new counter

% Define a command to show a solution if the solutions boolean is true
\newcommand{\solution}[1]{%
  \ifsolutions%
   \setcounter{linescount}{0} % Reset the counter
    Solution: 
    \begin{align*} #1 
    \end{align*}
    \setcounter{linescount}{\value{equation}}
  \else%
    \lines{\thelinescount}%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}            % begin the document

\begin{shortanswer}         % short answer section

\begin{shortquestion}{}
    \item\mrks{2} Solve for $x$:
    \begin{equation*}
        \displaystyle \frac{x+2}{5}-\frac{x-2}{3}=20
    \end{equation*}
    \solution{
        \frac{3(x+2)}{15}-\frac{5(x-2)}{15}&=20\\
        \frac{3x+6-5x+10}{15} &= 20\\
        \frac{-2x+16}{15} &=20\\
        -2x+16 &= 20 \times 15 \\
        -2x+16 &= 300 \\
        -2x &= 284 \\
        x &= \frac{284}{-2} \\
        x &= 142
    }
  \end{shortquestion}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Which packages and which document class are you using?

Comment: @ManuelCart I've got quite a few loaded in...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}    % change for bigger fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % must include
\usepackage{exam}                   % the exam.sty styles
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lineno}

\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
```